# Running libdatachannel over esp32 board

Tags: c, webrtc, esp32

I am using esp idf to develop my project. I downloaded libdatachannel in esp folder so now I have 2 directories in esp folder:

1. esp-idf
2. libdatachannel

I then updated CMakeLists.txt in the root of my project and added line

```
set(EXTRA_COMPONENT_DIRS "$ENV{IDF_PATH}/examples/common_components/protocol_examples_common $ENV{IDF_PATH}/../libdatachannel")
```

now when I try to build the project I get following callstack

> Executing task: ninja
>
> [0/1] Re-running CMake...
> -- Project is not inside a git repository, or git repository has no commits; will not use 'git describe' to determine PROJECT_VER.
> -- Building ESP-IDF components for target esp32 CMake Error at /Users/ayaz/esp/esp-idf/tools/cmake/component.cmake:219 (message):
> CMake Warning (dev) at build_properties.temp.cmake:7:
>
> ```
> Syntax Warning in cmake code at column 51
>
> Argument not separated from preceding token by whitespace.
> ```
>
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
>
> ```
> /Users/ayaz/esp/esp-idf/tools/cmake/scripts/component_get_requirements.cmake:3
> ```
>
> (include)
>
> This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress
> it.
>
> fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point
> /Volumes)
>
> Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not
> set).
>
> CMake Error at /Users/ayaz/esp/libdatachannel/CMakeLists.txt:2
> (project):
>
> ```
> project command is not scriptable
> ```
>
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
>
> ```
> /Users/ayaz/esp/esp-idf/tools/cmake/scripts/component_get_requirements.cmake:106
> ```
>
> (include)
> /Users/ayaz/esp/esp-idf/tools/cmake/scripts/component_get_requirements.cmake:124
> (__component_get_requirements)
>
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
> /Users/ayaz/esp/esp-idf/tools/cmake/build.cmake:491
> (__component_get_requirements)
> /Users/ayaz/esp/esp-idf/tools/cmake/project.cmake:378
> (idf_build_process)   CMakeLists.txt:10 (project)
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "/Volumes/Projects/ESP-Projects/websocket/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
> FAILED: build.ninja
> /Users/ayaz/.espressif/tools/cmake/3.20.3/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake
> --regenerate-during-build -S/Volumes/Projects/ESP-Projects/websocket -B/Volumes/Projects/ESP-Projects/websocket/build ninja: error: rebuilding 'build.ninja': subcommand failed
>
> - The terminal process "/bin/zsh '-c', 'ninja '" terminated with
>   exit code: 1.

**PROGRESS SO FAR:**

I am having following error while building toolchain

> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file
> "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed. Compiler:
> /Volumes/Extra/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
> Build flags:  Id flags:
>
> The output was: 1 ld: library not found for -lc++ clang: error: linker
> command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> Compiling the C compiler identification source file
> "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed. Compiler:
> /Volumes/Extra/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
> Build flags:  Id flags:
>
> The output was: 1 ld: library not found for -lSystem clang: error:
> linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

another problem is that esp32 uses xtensa-esp32-elf- compiler where as libdatachannel is getting compiled using Apple Clang. I need to modify sdkconfig so that all includes gets compiled using xtensa-esp32-elf-

```
# The following four lines of boilerplate have to be in your project's CMakeLists
# in this exact order for cmake to work correctly
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

# (Not part of the boilerplate)
# This example uses an extra component for common functions such as Wi-Fi and Ethernet connection.
set(EXTRA_COMPONENT_DIRS $ENV{IDF_PATH}/examples/common_components/protocol_examples_common)
include($ENV{IDF_PATH}/../libdatachannel/CMakeLists.txt)
include($ENV{ADF_PATH}/CMakeLists.txt)
include($ENV{IDF_PATH}/tools/cmake/project.cmake)
project(websocket_example)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you think this should work with ESP-IDF?

Comment: I have project where I need to use this library.

Comment: I need to use webrtc to load offers and ice candidates and transmit audio from microphone attached with esp lyrat. for this purpose I need to use libdatachannel.

Comment: It's written in C++. It wants to run over a POSIX-based system. ESP-IDF is C, not C++, which is a different and less capable language. ESP-IDF is not POSIX-compliant. As far as I know, libdatachannel is not compatible with ESP-IDF. You would have to write a layer adapting its C++ API to C and its dependency on POSIX to ESP-IDF's functions.

Comment: yes got that so far. Thanks for the response. This is what Amazon WEBRTC SDK is doing.